# Eclipse Activity Not Restarting on Code Change

Tags: android, eclipse

It used to be that when I changed a piece of code and ran the project, Eclipse would kill and restart the app on my phone. I'm now getting "**Warning: activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front**" whenever I try to run regardless if whether I've updated code or not. I have tried deleting and adding entire code segments then running and I'm still getting this. I'm now having to resort to actually manually killing the app on my phone whenever I want to update the code. Any clue as to what is going on?

Update: one thing that I've changed recently is that I've updated HTC sync manager which has the HTC USB drivers and reinstalled Google USB drivers. Could that be the reason?

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Tried cleaning, same behavior.

Comment: Close the app on your emulator. Then, re-run it. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

Normally It happens when you have not changed anything in your code. I had same error on emulator when I am not changing anything and still run the same code.

Answer (score 0):

K looks like that you heavent mentioned you activity  in manifest.
See this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).    Or u could try to reset eclipse to default.

And if it doesn't solves ur problem then please paste the error log here...